# Mysqlhotcopy message: audit_log_user_command(): Connection refused

Tags: mysql, backup

Im trying backup db. It works but give this message before backup process:

`audit_log_user_command(): Connection refused`

what this means?

Comment: This is a sudo error.<br>
How are you running mysqlhotcopy ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with sudo. Update to latest version.